# How to access 'can?' method from within cell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-cells

I'm using `cancan` and `cells` gems in my ruby-on-rails project.
**How to access `can?` method from within cell?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I've had to do exactly this. Try

```
class MyCell < Cell::Rails

  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions

end
```

If you're also using Devise, I had to do this:

```
class MyCell < Cell::Rails

  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  Devise::Controllers::Helpers.define_helpers(Devise::Mapping.new(:user, {}))

end
```

`#define_helpers` will add helper methods such as current_user and user_signed_in? to the cell.

Comment: hi qnm! what is the last `define_helpers` part needed for?

Comment: @dgilperez Take a look at [the code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L42) - you'll see this brings the devise helpers - current_user / user_signed_in? etc. into the cell as helpers.

Answer (score 4):

For those who happen to have a custom `current_ability()` method (in which you can change the name of current_user method and Ability class names):

```
class OrderCell < Cell::Rails
  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  delegate :current_ability, :to => :controller
end
```