# How can I access cancan helpers from within cells

Tags: cancan, cells, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey! How can I use the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) helpers like `can?` and `cannot?` from within [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) views?

Comment: Current workaround: Create a helper with the can? and cannot? method.

Comment: Answered in other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546892/how-to-access-can-method-from-within-cell